# Calculating dynamically the height of a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell, subviews, row-height

I am building a application without the IB and I am writing everything from scratch. I have a custom UITableViewCell and when I try to calculate the height, it behaves like there are no subviews. I could find a lot of discussion about dynamically setting the height, but nothing really about how to calculate it, based on the subviews and how and where to set the constraints. What I did is setting constraints for my first component - UIImageView and add them the contenView of my cell. What I get is 0.

I will appreciate any input on that or at least direction!

**heightForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar"];

    cell.imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;

    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-30-[image]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{ @"image": cell.imageView }];

    [cell.contentView addConstraints:constraints];

    NSArray *constraints2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[image]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{ @"image": cell.imageView}];

    [cell.contentView addConstraints:constraints2];

    [ NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.imageView attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0f];

     CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    NSLog(@"%f",height);

    return height;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this kind of problem is `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. You just return this in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method. You will have to set `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` to some value that is close to what you will get.

For instance, if you have 5 cells with height [100,200,250,270,300] you can set `estimatedRowHeight` to 220 (or something similar).

You can take a look at first answer at [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights) as well.

Comment: What I am getting is -1.

Comment: Because it is calculated later on, you use this value to let uitableview know that it will caluclate the height. Do you get UI right?

Comment: I guess not... I get a new warning,though: Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead. Shouldn't the content view be set automatically to a value when a set the constrains of the UIImageView ?

Comment: try to implement estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath, that should get rid of the warning. I am using this kind of approach in few projects, and it renders ui right, with fullfilling all the constraints.

Comment: Not working either and I am getting the same warning. What I am thinking is that I am missing something when building the custom cell, but I don't know yet what.

Comment: Ah, you are right, you are accessing default elements for uitableviewcell, what you should do is create new class to subclass UITableViewCell, create xib and create elements there. I am not 100% sure but I think that you cannot modify position of the UITableviewCell default elements ( image, title, details title, accessories)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83200/discussion-between-nickcatib-and-neli-chakarova).

Comment: What I did and what you suggested were both right. The only thing I was missing in mine was that I  had only the constraint to one of the borders of the superview and I needed both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that will work, or that it is correct but try this way

```
static NSInteger someCell = 1;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [UITableViewCell new];
    cell.tag = someCell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.tag == someCell) return 100.;
    return 30.;
}
```